# Group by applied seperately for each type of column in sql

Tags: mysql, query

The table I'm working on is as follows :
[image]

What I want to do is to Group By 'Month' for each Person, that is use the Group By statement multiple times for each person. I want the output as follows :

[image]

Please tell me how I can achieve this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Show us the rest of the query.  `GROUP BY` implies that you have a `COUNT(*)` or `SUM(*)` or some other "aggregate".

The output you showed seems to be `ORDER BY person, month` but no `GROUP BY`.

Still there is another issue -- Ordering by month would put the string "February" before "January" because they are strings.  Do you have the data in a `DATE` column?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following

```
SELECT
    `PERSON`
   ,`MONTH`
   ,SUM(AMOUNT) Amounts
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY `PERSON`,`MONTH`;
```

If you would like to include every total per person as well, you can do this

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(`PERSON`,'All People') people
   ,IFNULL(`MONTH`,'All Months') months
   ,SUM(AMOUNT) Amounts
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY `PERSON`,`MONTH` WITH ROLLUP;
```

### UPDATE 2022-12-14 12:18 EST

If you have a `date`,`datetime`,`timestamp` column (call it `DATEFIELD`) in `yourtable`, you would adjust the queries as follows:

```
SELECT
    `PERSON`
   ,DATE_FORMAT(`DATEFIELD`,'%Y-%m-%b') as `MONTH`
   ,SUM(AMOUNT) Amounts
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY `PERSON`,DATE_FORMAT(`DATEFIELD`,'%Y-%m-%b');
```

and

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(`PERSON`,'All People') people
   ,IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(`DATEFIELD`,'%Y-%m-%b'),'All Months') as `MONTH`
   ,SUM(AMOUNT) Amounts
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY `PERSON`,DATE_FORMAT(`DATEFIELD`,'%Y-%m-%b') WITH ROLLUP;
```

NOTE : DATE_FORMAT(`DATEFIELD`,'%Y-%m-%b') will write out the Date Like This

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT('2022-09-14 12:34:56','%Y-%m-%b') dt;
+-------------+
| dt          |
+-------------+
| 2022-09-Sep |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```